# RMSE for model-selection

Tags: regression, model-selection, r-squared, mse, rms

Can I use RMSE,r2 or other metric to compare models of different datasets and variables?
And if I have the same dataset but different variables?

Comment: Same dataset meaning the same $y$ that you try to predict multiple different ways?

Comment: Yes. In the first question I have two different datasets (i.e. a dataset with adults and other with children). In the second question, I have only one dataset (i.e. a dataset with adults) however, I have two different predictions (or models) for Y.

Comment: Why aren’t you combining the data sets?

Comment: Because I want to make predictions for adults and children separetedly. And I want to compare segmented models to combined one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could 1) fix the dataset and use RMSE, R2 or other metrics to compare the performance of your two models/predictions, then you could find which model is better; 2) fix the model and use metrics to compare the performance on two datasets(you may choose the model having okay performance on at least one dataset to show the prediction is not just noise) then you could get the conclusion which dataset is easy to predict and which one is harder.